# Try to using ajax in laravel but return 404

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, laravel

I try to get data by json using ajax.

My controller:

```
public function getFreeDay(Reservation $reservation): JsonResponse
{
    //here will be other data, this is for test
    try {
        return response()->json([
            'status' => 'success'
        ]);
    } catch (\Exception $e) {
        return response()->json([
            'status' => 'error',
            'message' => 'Wystąpił Błąd'
        ])->setStatusCode(500);
    }
}
```

Route:

```
Route::post('/rezerwacja/{reservation}', [ReservationController::class, 'getFreeDay'])->name('getFreeDay');
```

ajax:

```
    $("select#select-service").change(function () {
        $.ajax({
            headers: {
                'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
            },
            method: "GET",
            url: getFreeDay + $(this).val(),

            //data: {id: $(this).data('id')}
        })
            .done(function (data) {

                window.location.reload();
            })
            .fail(function (data) {
                console.log($(this).data('id'))
                console.log(data.responseJSON.message);
            });
});
const getFreeDay = "{{ url('rezerwacja')}}/";
```

HTML:

```
  <select class="form-select" id="select-service">
                <option  selected>Wybierz usługe</option>
                @foreach($services as $service)
                    <option value="{{$service->id}}">
                        {{$service->service_name}}
                    </option>
                @endforeach
            </select>
```

but each time, when i run ajax by my select list item it return 404.
I know that something is wrong with url and routing but i don't know what.

Comment: The documentation has a section on [Generating URLs To Named Routes](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/routing#generating-urls-to-named-routes)

Comment: log the javascript generated url in browser console and see what needs to be tweaked here.

Answer (score 0):

url and route(name) is different, in your url you used "getFreeDay" which is used as `{{route('getFreeDay')}}` instead

```
$.ajax({
    type : 'POST',
    url : '{{ route("getFreeDay") }}',
    data : data
    dataType : 'json'
}).done(function(){})
```

Comment: That would be missing the required parameter `reservation`